# Download PDF file without saving it on server nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am creating a PDF file from HTML using html-pdf. Now I want to download the file on button click on HTML. I know how to ForceDownload a File. Now I want to know how I can force download the PDF file generated.

PDF generation Code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('PDF.html', 'utf8');
var options = { "height": "9in",        // allowed units: mm, cm, in, px
  "width": "8in" ,orientation : "portrait","header": {
    "height": "5mm",border: {
    "top": "2in",            // default is 0, units: mm, cm, in, px
    "right": "1in",
    "bottom": "2in",
    "left": "1.5in"
  },
    "base": "",
  },};


pdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream){
  stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('foo.pdf'));
});
```

File Download Code:

```
var http = require('http');


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var text_ready = "This is a content of a txt file."


res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/force-download','Content-disposition':'attachment; filename=file.txt'});

res.end( text_ready );
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

Is there a way I can combine both of these? Or a better way to download the PDF file generated without saving it? I got both of them to work separately. I am pretty new to Node.js.

Answer (score 2):

You can pipe your pdf to response since responce implements [Writable Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) :

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    fs.readFile('./PDFFormat.html', 'utf8', function (err, html) {
        if (err) {
            //error handling
        }
        pdf.create(html).toStream(function (err, stream) {
            if (err) {
                //error handling
            }
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'application/force-download',
                'Content-disposition': 'attachment; filename=file.pdf'
            });
            stream.pipe(res);
        });
    });
}).listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit with a small example. I am new to this.

Comment: I updated my comment. Hope this helps. Check the node documentation as well.